# String pattern matching - method needs improving

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to build simple pattern matching in a string.

ie., Given a `template` of: `"Hello ${1}"` and an `input` of `"Hello world"`, I'd like to be able to return a map of `1='world'`.

This test demonstrates what I'm trying to acheive:

```
@Test
public void detectsTokenValues()
{
    Properties properties = formatter.getTokenValues("${1}/andThen/${2}/followedBy/${3}","start/andThen/middle/followedBy/end");
    assertThat((String) properties.get("1"), equalTo("start"));
    assertThat((String) properties.get("2"), equalTo("middle"));
    assertThat((String) properties.get("3"), equalTo("end"));
}
```

Here's my implementation.  It works, but I feel like it's convoluted, and I suspect there's Regex or other JDK native features I could be using to make it simpler.

```
// Matches ${0} - ${9999} etc.,  But not ${variblesWithWords}
private static final Pattern NUMERIC_VARIABLES = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{([0-9]+?)\\}");


Properties getTokenValues(String template, String input) {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    Matcher matcher = NUMERIC_VARIABLES.matcher(sourcestring);
    final int variableWrapperLength = "${}".length();
    int accumulativeOffset = 0;
    while (matcher.find())
    {
        String variableName = matcher.group(1);
        String value = null;
        if (matcher.end() >= template.length())
        {
            value = input.substring(matcher.start() + accumulativeOffset);
        } else {
            // Find the character after the variable in the template.
            // This serves as the end-delimeter in the input string.
            String endDelimiter = template.substring(matcher.end(),matcher.end()+1);
            int variableEndIndex = findEndDelimiterIndex(input, matcher.start() + 1,
                    endDelimiter);
            value = input.substring(matcher.start() + accumulativeOffset, variableEndIndex);

            // Adjust the accumulative offset to account for the difference
            // in lengths between the variableName (eg., ${1}) 
            // and the the actual value (eg., 'foo') 
            accumulativeOffset += value.length() - (variableWrapperLength + variableName.length());
        }

        if (value != null)
            properties.put(variableName, value);
    }
    return properties;
}

private int findEndDelimiterIndex(String input, int fromIndex,
        String endDelimiter) {

    // Find the first instance of the delimiter in the input string
    // that occurs after the start of our  matches variable.
    if (fromIndex > input.length())
    {
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
    int variableEndIndex = input.indexOf(endDelimiter,fromIndex);
    return variableEndIndex;
}
```

How can I improve this method?

Comment: `NUMERIC_VARIABLES.matcher(sourcestring);` shouldn't be `NUMERIC_VARIABLES.matcher(template)`?

Answer (score 3):

The function `getTokenValues` is actually a pattern matching function. It just uses a different syntax than the pattern format of `java.util.regex`.

I suggest you to convert your pattern string (the one with `$` signs) into a valid `Pattern`.

```
${1}/andThen/${2}/followedBy/${3}
```

becomes

```
(.+?)/andThen/(.+?)/followedBy/(.+?)
```

And then you can use `Pattern.matcher` to find the content of the groups. There is still one thing missing : the fact that the numbering of the original pattern is lost. For that, you can parse the original pattern string to extract those numbers, to create a mapping table.

When you convert your pattern string into a Pattern, be careful to escape the substrings between the `$` using `Pattern.quote()`.

I don't know if this solution would be an improvement of yours, but it's an alternative to consider.

### Edit

The implementation of my solution :

```
Map<String, String> getTokenValues(String pattern, String str) {
    Map<String, String> res = new HashMap<String, String>();
    List<String> identifiers = new ArrayList<String>();

    Pattern dollarRgx = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{([0-9]+?)\\}");
    Matcher dollarMatcher = dollarRgx.matcher(pattern);
    StringBuilder convRgxBd = new StringBuilder();
    int lastEnd = 0;
    while(dollarMatcher.find()) {
        String before = pattern.substring(lastEnd, dollarMatcher.start());
        convRgxBd.append(Pattern.quote(before));
        convRgxBd.append("(.+?)");
        lastEnd = dollarMatcher.end();
        identifiers.add(dollarMatcher.group(1));
    }
    String after = pattern.substring(lastEnd, pattern.length());
    convRgxBd.append(Pattern.quote(after));

    Pattern convRgx = Pattern.compile(convRgxBd.toString());
    Matcher convMatcher = convRgx.matcher(str);
    if(convMatcher.matches()) {
        for(int i = 0; i < convMatcher.groupCount(); i++) {
            String id = identifiers.get(i);
            res.put(id, convMatcher.group(i+1));
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a side note: You could avoid the `(String)` casting if you used a `Map` (a `HashMap`, for example) instead of `Properties`. `Properties` has a  design flaw: it should not extend `Hashtable`.

*Effetcive Java, 2nd Edition* mentions it in its *Item 16: Favor composition over inheritance*:

> In the case of `Properties`, the designers intended that only strings be
>   allowed as keys and values, but direct access to the underlying `Hashtable` allows
>   this invariant to be violated. Once this invariant is violated, 
>   it is no longer possible
>   to use other parts of the `Properties` API (`load` and `store`). 
>   By the time this problem 
>   was discovered, it was too late to correct it because clients depended on the
>   use of nonstring keys and values.

---

Here is an alternate implementation based on *@barjak*'s idea:

```
private static final String NON_GROUP_REGEX = ".*?";
private static final String GROUP_REGEX = "(.*?)";

public Map<String, String> getTokenValues2(final String template, final String input) {
    final Map<String, String> result = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

    final List<String> variableNames = getVariableNames(template);
    // TODO: check duplicated variables here

    for (final String variableName: variableNames) {
        final String value = getValueForVariable(template, input, variableName);
        result.put(variableName, value);
    }
    return result;
}

private List<String> getVariableNames(final String template) {
    final List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    final Matcher matcher = NUMERIC_VARIABLES.matcher(template);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        final String variableName = matcher.group(1);
        result.add(variableName);
    }
    return result;
}

private String getValueForVariable(final String template, final String input, 
        final String variableName) {
    final String variableRegex = createVariableRegex(template, variableName);
    final Matcher variableMatcher = Pattern.compile(variableRegex).matcher(input);
    if (!variableMatcher.matches()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("template: " + template + ", input: " 
                + input + ", variableName " + variableName);
    }
    final String value = variableMatcher.group(1);
    return value;
}

private String createVariableRegex(String template, 
        final String groupMatcherVariableName) {
    template = replaceNumericVariableToGroupMatcher(template, groupMatcherVariableName);
    template = replaceNumericVariablesToNonGroupMatchers(template);
    return template;
}

private String replaceNumericVariablesToNonGroupMatchers(final String template) {
    return NUMERIC_VARIABLES.matcher(template)
        .replaceAll(Matcher.quoteReplacement(NON_GROUP_REGEX));
}

private String replaceNumericVariableToGroupMatcher(final String template, 
        final String variableName) {
    final Pattern variableNamePattern = Pattern.compile(Pattern
        .quote("${" + variableName + "}"));
    final String quotedVariableNameReplacementRegexp = 
        Matcher.quoteReplacement(GROUP_REGEX);
    return variableNamePattern.matcher(template)
        .replaceFirst(quotedVariableNameReplacementRegexp);
}
```